# Getting a "Duplicate column name 'id'" error when using gorm's AutoMigrate

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a model in `gorm` that looks something like this:

```
type MyModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID                               int `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT;not null;unique"`
    CountryID                        int `gorm:"not null"`
    SomeID                       int `gorm:"not null;unique"`
...
...
```

But when I run:

```
server.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(&models.MyModel{})
```

I see that the following query is being run on the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_model` (`id` int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,`created_at` timestamp NULL,`updated_at` timestamp NULL,`deleted_at` timestamp NULL,`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,`country_id` int NOT NULL,varchar(255),`has_self` boolean,`limit` boolean , PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id`))
```

And I get the error:

> Error 1060: Duplicate column name 'id'

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `gorm.Model` already has an `ID` field, so either remove or rename yours, or don't embed `gorm.Model` (if that's even possible).

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html

Comment: I thought that may be the case, it's weird that all of the online `gorm` tutorials include an `ID` field in the model.
I imagine it's also unique and auto incremented by default? (stupid question, i know, but just making sure)

Comment: ... looking at the generated `CREATE TABLE` command I would say yes, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` is being used and both `id` columns, the original and yours, are included at the end in the `PRIMARY KEY` clause. The struct tag in the model's source says only `primary_key`... I'm not sure if that by default means auto-increment as well or whether they assign auto-increment using some other rule.